# How to perform Incremental mapReduce over string data (JSON)?

Tags: json, string, mongodb, mapreduce

I am working with Geo-Spatial data in MongoDB and trying to query from data using Incremental mapReduce.(I am trying to find the areas that have intersect with each other)

my collection contains documents of the following prototype(the bbox is longitude and latitude):

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("577be972e0977965a62e3264"),
"value" : {
    "Name" : "43456",
    "type" : "zip",
    "bbox" : [
        -82.856831,
        41.62814,
        -82.793069,
        41.724549
    ]
}
}
```

in my mapreduce code I am trying to find the areas which have intersection with each other, to do so I have used "incremental mapReduce". thus, I have defined an array in reduce function and i want to put all areas involved interception in this array. (in map function I have put all collection in one document [emit(1, this.value)], in order to search among it using nested for loop).

when I ran this code in MongoDB, the output of the reduce function is null. What I am guessing is that the incremental part of the code might be wrong but still I am not sure. On the other hand if it is really wrong I do not know how can I fix it.

here is my mapReduce code:

```
var Mapper=function(){

var key=1;
var value={
id: this._id,
Name: this.value.Name,
Type: this.value.type,
Bbox: this.value.bbox
};
emit (key, value);
}
var Reducer=function(key, val){

var reduceObj={
id:0,
Name: 0,
Type: 0,
Bbox: 0};

for(var i=0; i<(val.lenght)-1; i++)
{ for(var j=1; j<val.lenght; j++)
{
if((val[i].Type=="zip") && (val[j].Type=="water")&&
(((val[i].Bbox[0]==val[j]. Bbox[0] ||  val[i].Bbox[0]== val[j].Bbox[2] ||          val[i].Bbox[2] == val[j].Bbox[0] || val[i].Bbox[2] == val[j].Bbox[2])||( val[i].Bbox[0] <= val[j].Bbox[0]  && val[i].Bbox[0] <= val[j].Bbox[2]) ||( val[i].Bbox[0] <= val[j].Bbox[0] && val[i].Bbox[0] <= val[j].Bbox[2]) )&&( (val[i].Bbox[1] == val[j].Bbox[1] ||  val[i].Bbox[1] == val[j].Bbox[3] || val[i].Bbox[3] == val[j].Bbox[1] || val[i].Bbox[3] == val[j].Bbox[3])||( val[i].Bbox[1] <= val[i].Bbox[1]  && val[i].Bbox[1] <= val[j].Bbox[3]) ||( val[i].Bbox[1] <= val[j].Bbox[1] && val[i].Bbox[1] <= val[j].Bbox[3]))))

{
reduceObj.id=val.id;
reduceObj.Name=val.Name;
reduceObj.Type=val.Type;
reduceObj.Bbox=val.Bbox;

}

}}
return reduceObj;
}
db.ALL.mapReduce(Mapper, Reducer, {
out: "Intersects"})
```

I would be really appreciated if somebody help me

Comment: The question in its current form will probably be put on hold soon. You should rewrite it stating at least what's wrong with the piece of code and what is the expected output.

Comment: I have edited it and added the problem. sorry for inconvenient and thank you for your comment.